# What does x86 `movq %rsp, (%rdi)` and `movq (%rsi), %rsp` do and how are they different?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, att

I am playing with some "just for fun" code that implements custom threading.

Of course, it has to implement context switching too, and this bit comes from the context-switching function:

```
        movq %rsp, (%rdi)
        
        movq (%rsi), %rsp
```

I am not that much familiar with x86 and assembly in general and having hard times to figure out what is happening.

Seems to me that `movq (%rsi), %rsp` dereferences a (virtual) memory address stored in the `%rsi` and copies 8 bytes (since `q`) to the `%rsp`.

However, I can't figure out what does the `movq %rsp, (%rdi)` line do? `(%rdi)` seems to be a target register, i.e. the one that will take new value.. however it does not match with the brackets around it... as far as I understand `(...)` means dereferencing..

Please, explain.

Comment: It's the same dereferencing as in the other case. The destination is a memory location pointed to by `rdi`.

Comment: @Jester so it would copy what `%rsp` has inside it (without dereferencing) to a memory location that starts at the byte pointed by the `%rdi`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct, `(%register)` means to dereference the value in the register and use it as a memory location.

So (in AT&T syntax):

`movq %rsp, (%rdi)` means "copy the value in `rsp` to the location whose memory address is stored in `rdi`".

and

`movq (%rsi), %rsp` means "copy the value from the location whose memory address is stored in `rsi` to `rsp`".

The purpose appears to be to save the current stack pointer (save location pointed to by `rdi`) and load a new stack pointer (load location pointed to by `rsi`) during a thread switch.